# How to create a variable by setting a custom identifier as variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, ecmascript-6

This looks crazy but it was a much-needed solution for my application to solve the problem of dynamic initialization...

when I inject the services dynamically I would like it to be identified by my own variable which matches the service.

Here is what >I want.

```
$rootScope.arr = ['MasterLookupService', 'PrinterService'];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  var arr[i] = $injector.get(arr[i]);

}

// it will end up something like this
```

var MasterLookupService = $injector.get('MasterLookupService');

I tried but none helped

```
   // $rootScope.customObj = {
   //    MasterLookUpService: $injector.get('MasterLookupService'),
   //    PrinterService: $injector.get('PrinterService')
   // }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Jquery but this might be what I understand you need.

```
var arr = ['MasterLookupService', 'PrinterService'];

for(var i =0 ;i < arr.length; i++){
    var varname = arr[i];
    window[varname] = 'value '+i;
}

alert(MasterLookupService);
```

[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object represents a window containing a DOM document. You may use other object depending upon your environment.